# Creating a progress bar in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have been searching for awhile for a tutorial or anything, but cant seem to find anything. What im looking to to is in my web application build a progress bar similar to that in the window.form controls. Any help or any kind of direction would be very helpful. Im not looking for someone do it for me, just a link or some pointers of how to get started

Answer (score 2):

A progress bar is a control that holds 3 major attributes : (you should look at  System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar to have an idea of what ProgreeBar are made of)

- a minimum
- a maximum
- a value

you have to re-render asynchronously and regularly to update status of the control to the user.

Basically the only big difference from WinForms ProgressBar and Net.UI. Progreebar are the graphical control used to render the progress . So you could use a size fixed graphical control (e.g a label) and from min to max add some content in it.

In most cases it is not the value changed that raise an event to be handled , but handling an event that update the value of your progress bar. Look at the example in this page : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.aspx

PS : It exists some (free or not) .NET ProgressBar like Neat Upload.

Have fun with it :P

Answer (score 0):

In the design page(.aspx) you can use ScriptManager control and a UpdateProgress control that are under AJAX Extension category in the Visual Studio’s toolbox. You can use your own GIF file, as well.

You can check the below link:

http://www.webcodeexpert.com/2013/05/show-progress-image-using.html